# Using log4j with inherited classes

Tags: java, inheritance, log4j

I am instantiating a log4j object inside of a class which inherits most of the methods and attributes from a parent class.  Right now I'm getting logging messages from the subclass only.  How can I get logging messages to output in both the super class and subclass?

EDIT: The way I am do the logging is that I have an instance variable in both the subclass and superclass, so it would look something like the following:

```
public class SuperClass {
/**
 * Logger for this class
 */
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SuperClass.class); 

/* Rest of code goes here */
} // end SuperClass
```

And the same for the subclass.

My log4j configuration:

```
## gps log4j.rootLogger==ERROR, clientLog, catissuecoreclientLog

log4j.rootLogger==DEBUG, clientLog, catissuecoreclientLog
### direct messages to file hibernate.log ###

log4j.appender.clientLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.clientLog.File=./log/client.log
log4j.appender.clientLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.clientLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.catissuecoreclientLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.catissuecoreclientLog.File=./log/catissuecoreclient.log
log4j.appender.catissuecoreclientLog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.catissuecoreclientLog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

### set log levels - for more verbose logging change 'info' to 'debug' ###

#log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
#log4j.rootLogger=warn, file
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info

### log just the SQL
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

### log JDBC bind parameters ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info

### log schema export/update ###
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=debug

### log cache activity ###
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=debug

### log JDBC resource acquisition
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug

### enable the following line if you want to track down connection ###
### leakages when using DriverManagerConnectionProvider ###
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider=trace
```

Comment: The logger instance variable that's in the code sample above.

Comment: I take it double equals sign in `log4j.rootLogger==DEBUG` is a typo? Also, stdout appender is not specified in log4j.rootLogger

Comment: Okay, I removed the extra equals sign and uncommented the log4j.rootLogger line - we'll see how it works out.

Comment: Still not getting log messages from the superclass after changing the config file.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make the logger visible in  super class as well.

Normally the setup is to create a logger static variable in each class to allow each class to have different logging level.
e.g.

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger( ClassName.class.getName() );
```

Where you enter your class's name instead of ClassName

Answer (score 1):

Umm... by actually logging them?

You need to invoke log4j's logging methods (`debug()`, `info()`, `error()`, etc...) from whatever method of whatever class you want to log message from. You can then configure (in your `log4j.properties`) what messages are visible / logged / go to what log file / etc... per class level (if you so choose).

Comment: I do know how to invoke the logging methods - that's not the issue.  The issue is that I am not getting any of the logging statements from the superclass.  I have configured the level of logging to be DEBUG.

Comment: Can you post your log4j configuration? Is logging for both `SuperClass` and subclass set to DEBUG level?

Comment: I posted the contents of my config file in the original question.  And, yes, I also set the level of the logger instance variables in both the subclass and superclass to DEBUG.