# log4j: How do I enable logging in a subclass for a method in a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, log4j

I have a logging statement in a method of my Superclass. I want to enable this statement only if the method is called for an Object of SubClassA.

```
public class SuperClass
{
private static Logger               logger  = Logger.getLogger(SuperClass.class);
public void test()
{
    logger.info("test...");
}
}
```

...

```
public class SubClassA extends SuperClass
{
private static Logger               logger  = Logger.getLogger(SubClassA.class);
}
```

...

```
public class SubClassB extends SuperClass
{
private static Logger               logger  = Logger.getLogger(SubClassB.class);
public static void main(String[] p_Args)
{
    SubClassA subClassA = new SubClassA();
    SubClassB subClassB = new SubClassB();
    subClassA.test();
    subClassB.test();
}
}
```

How do I enable logging in test() only for SubclassA?

log4j.logger.SuperClass=info  //enables logging in the test() method for both Subclasses

log4j.logger.SubClassA=info   //does nothing  for the test() method

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406931/using-log4j-with-inherited-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, because logger doesn't know anything about classes and inheritance. A logger name is a simple textual name like "a.b.c.d". Maybe you could use subclass's class in super class, i.e. instead of:

```
private static Logger               logger  = Logger.getLogger(SuperClass.class);
```

use:

```
private Logger               logger  = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
```

or you could use both:

```
private Logger               subLogger  = Logger.getLogger(getClass());
private static Logger        logger  = Logger.getLogger(SuperClass.class);
```

and then you could use more sophisticated logic:

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled() || subLogger.isInfoEnabled())
{
...
}
```

But if I were you, I would not use this magic, because logging should be as simple as possible (but not simpler).

Comment: I personally prefer the case with Logger.getLogger(getClass())

Comment: @lechlukasz I don't! If you use Logger.getLogger(SuperClass.class) it's much easier to find out which bit of code logged a line, because you see exact class name in a log file. In case of getClass(), you will see subclass name, and you also should look around all superclasses for a logged line.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to enable logging in **this one** subclass you should define the logger (or an additional logger to the standard package/class named one) to a specific string (`Logger.getLogger("SpecialSubClassALogger")` and use it in `SuperClass` to log. You can then use `log4j.logger.SpecialSubClassALogger=info`.